# Xstream : unmarshalling inner classes

Tags: java, unmarshalling, xstream

I would like to marshall and unmarshall objects whose fields are of their class's inner class (synthetic class if I'm not wrong).

```
class A {
    private B field_b=null;
    public static class B {
        public static B B1 = new B("b1");
        public static B B2 = new B("b2");

        private final String name;
        private B(String name) {
            this.name=name;
            }
        }
    public B getBforName(String name) {
        if (B1.name.equals(name) return B1;            
        else if (B2.name.equals(name) return B2;
        else return null;            
    }
```

And produce and read from an XML:

```
<A>
    <field_B>b1</field_B>
</A>
```

The writing part is easy.

The reading part is more complicated.

I would like to write a converter:

```
public class BConverter implements Converter {
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return B.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ;
    }
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        // ...
    }
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        A parent_v1 = (A) context.getCurrentObject(); // !!! always empty
        A parent_v2 = (A) context.get("current_unmarshalled_A");

        return parent_v2.getBforName((String)reader.getValue());

    }
}
```

The `context.getCurrentObject()` returns null and seems to be obsolete (from forums I read).

The `context.get("current_unmarshalled_A")`would require that I put in this unMarshallingContext that key and the A object being unmarshalled. I don't find to do that without writing an AConverter. And that is not neat as I would loose the default unmarshalling behaviour for the class A.

Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is cleanest way to that but it works.

I use a static method in the B class ...

```
class A {
    private B field_b=null;
    public static class B {
        public static B B1 = new B("b1");
        public static B B2 = new B("b2");

        public static B getForName(String name) {
            if (B1.name.equals(name) return B1;            
            else if (B2.name.equals(name) return B2;
            else return null;            
        }

        private final String name;
        private B(String name) {
            this.name=name;
            }
    }
```

... and reflection in the Converter

```
public class BConverter implements Converter {
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return B.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ;
    }
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        writer.setValue(((B)source).getName())
    }
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        try {
            Method method = context.getRequiredType().getMethod("getForName", String.class);
            final String v = reader.getValue();
            Object b= method.invoke(null, v);
            if (b== null)
                throw new ConversionException("Could not retrieve a B object for \"" + v + "\"");
            return b;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ConversionException("Error while retrieving a B object", ex);
        }
    }
}
```